# Is there a max character limit for the count in WP8 live tiles?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to work out which live tile template(s) to use, and need to know if the three templates impose limits on the max count displayed. This doesn't seem to be in the design guidelines: does anyone know?

This could be an issue as our current service has a massive maximum (5 digits!)

Answer (score 4):

After **99**, it'll show **99+**

I guess that's another detail that we forgot to put in the public documentation.